# Field validation regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

Which is the correct way to create a regex of .net's ValidationExpression attribute for RegularExpressionValidator if I want to restrict the input of a textbox to `"t-" + any 6 letters (no digits)` i.e "`t-jblogg`"

`t-[a-z]*` but thats for `t-` followed by any `letter/combination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `^t-\p{L}{6}$`. This should accept any string which starts with `t`, is followed by a `-` and 6 letters. The `\p{L}` denote any letter from any language (as stated [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)). If you want to just restrict it to English letters then just use this: `^t-[A-Za-z]{6}$`

Comment: @sd_dracula: If this solved your problem, please tick the answer as correct. This will affect statistics on your profile and encourage others to help you should have any questions in the future.

Comment: I did. just waiting for the 5 mins to pass so I could submit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = "^t-[A-Za-z]{6}$"
```

Comment: To quote http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html: \w stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = "^t-[a-z]{6}$";
```